# Why isn't the child route working in angular?

Tags: angular

Here is the relevant code for the routing module ts file:

```js
    const routes: Routes = [{
        path: '',
        component: LoginPageComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'dashboard',
        component: DashboardPageComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'dashboard/:id',
        component: DashboardPageComponent,
        children: [{
          path: 'home',
          component: HomeComponent
        }]
      },
      {
        path: '**',
        component: LoginPageComponent
      },
    ];
```

Here is my dashboard component:

```html
<app-sidenav></app-sidenav>
<app-bar></app-bar>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

When I navigate to the dashboard/home directly, the HomeComponent does not load. Why is this?

Note: I tried removing the :id.

Comment: Well you may have _tried_ removing the `id:` but you must remove it.

Comment: Alright...I removed the :id. did not help

Comment: Tip: turn on tracing in `Router Module.forRoot(routes, options)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your path for home component isn't right. Removing `:id` from `path: 'dashboard/:id'` works fine.

I've created a demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-basic-example-s1ta81?file=app/app.routing.module.ts)

Answer (score 2):

Since you have defined `home` route inside `dashboard/id` segment, you can not directly access `/home` by doing `dashboard/home`, because this pattern will not match any of routing definition.

You must specify parent segment `dashboard/id` before accessing child segment `/home` route). All together mention **`dashboard/someid/home`** as it will try to match whole URL `dashboard/someid/home` with registered route definition, and out of which inital `dashboard/someid` pattern will match and it will render `UserDashboardPageComponent` later it tries to search for remaining pattern `/home` which matches with the `/home` child path, accordingly it will help render `HomeComponent` inside `router-outlet` of `UserDashboardPageComponent` component

Comment: Can you please rephrase this...I did not understand. My parent segment is dashboard and I want the child segment to be homepage.

Comment: @ParthAgarwal I did rephrase, let me know if it make sense now. :) Thanks :) Does that work what I suggested?

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add that there are a few issues with your Route Config that you can fix:

```
const routes: Routes = [{
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginPageComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    component: DashboardPageComponent,
    children: [{
      path: 'home',
      component: HomeComponent
    }]
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/login',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    component: LoginPageComponent
  },
];
```

Also, you're loading the same component `DashboardPageComponent` on `/dashboard` and `/dashboard/:id`. Consider defining a specific Component for `/dashboard/:id`

Comment: But I want the login component to load on a blank route

Comment: IT will. You've placed a catch all route in the end.

Comment: But thats for an invalid or 404 route. The start of the app, the first thing to load is login component. Anyways, I tried getting rid of what you asked. Did not make a difference. The home component does not load on dashboard/home.

Comment: But then why have you placed `LoginComponent` in `**`? And why same Component on `/dashboard` and `/dashboard/:id`?

Comment: Would you please consider creating a StackBlitz?

Comment: I have placed login component in ** as well because I want login to act as a 404. If the page is not found, you go to login.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179268/discussion-between-parth-agarwal-and-siddharth-ajmera).